# Visualizing Kinect data from two Turtlebots in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, kinect, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I am trying to run two Turtlebots in Gazebo and have one observe the other. I encountered the common error of one of the turtlebots only showing up as wheels, but by using a hack I am able to see both Turtlebots fully by closing the Gazebo GUI and reopening it again with rosrun gazebo gui.

The problem arises when I try to have one robot observe the other using its kinect and RVIZ. I can see the topics /camera/image_raw and /camera/depth/points (no namespace) from the turtlebot that originally fully appeared in gazebo. The other robot, though, appears only as wheels in RVIZ even though it is fully visible in Gazebo!

I figure there is two ways of solving this. 1) Actually remedying the problem of one of the Turtlebots not fully appearing originally in Gazebo instead of using the hack(which I have no idea how to do) 2) Observe the Turtlebot that fully appears from the others Kinect. There are topics /robot1/depth/image_raw and /robot1/depth/camera_info being published (and similarly for robot2) but when I set the topic to /robot1/depth/image_raw RVIZ looks for camerainfo on /robot2/depth/camera_info and vice versa and says no camerainfo received. I get just an image of a horizontal white line.

These probably coincide but I am hoping some of you know better than me.
I am using the following launch file to launch the Gazebo world with the 2 turtlebots in it simultaneously:

Where robot1 and robot2.launch are identical files except for the robots and nodes use different namespaces so that I can control the robots separately, and I have successfully written a teleop node to allow me to do this.

So how can I have one Turtlebot observe the other (not just its wheels)? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

-Alan

**UPDATE**

So here is the list of topics being published or subscribed:

/camera/camera_info

/camera/depth/points

/camera/image_raw

/camera/image_raw/compressed

/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions

/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates

/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth

/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions

/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates

/camera/image_raw/theora

/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions

/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates

/clock

/diagnostics

/diagnostics_agg

/diagnostics_toplevel_state

/gazebo/link_states

/gazebo/model_states

/gazebo/parameter_descriptions

/gazebo/parameter_updates

/gazebo/set_link_state

/gazebo/set_model_state

/robot1/depth/camera_info

/robot1/depth/image_raw

/robot1/imu/data

/robot1/initialpose

/robot1/joint_states

/robot1/move_base_simple/goal

/robot1/odom

/robot1/robot_pose_ekf/odom

/robot1/scan

/robot1/set_hfov

/robot1/set_update_rate

/robot1/turtlebot_node/cmd_vel

/robot1/turtlebot_node/joint_states

/robot1/turtlebot_node/odom

/robot1/turtlebot_node/sensor_state

/robot2/depth/camera_info

/robot2/depth/image_raw

/robot2/imu/data

/robot2/joint_states

/robot2/odom

/robot2/robot_pose_ekf/odom

/robot2/scan

/robot2/set_hfov

/robot2/set_update_rate

/robot2/turtlebot_node/cmd_vel

/robot2/turtlebot_node/joint_states

/robot2/turtlebot_node/odom

/robot2/turtlebot_node/sensor_state

/rosout

/rosout_agg

/tf

As you can see, I have the majority of topics specify for which robot they belong, but not the /camera topics. So, I guess the questions I need to be asking are:

1. What Gazebo plugin(s) are responsible for publishing the /camera topics? I figure I can use namespaces in them in order to specify to RVIZ which robot's camera feed I want to see.
2. Why isn't the whole Turtlebot showing up in RVIZ and how can I fix it?

Thanks again!
-Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63179/visualizing-kinect-data-from-two-turtlebots-in-gazebo/) by [ajhamlet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4140/ajhamlet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The problem you have **with respect to rviz** is due to malformed tf. When you are using multiple robots, you need to resolve the tf data for each of the robots by adding a "tf_prefix". By doing so all the links of the robot have unique names like robot1_tf/base_link, robot2_tf/odom etc and tf trees can be constructed for both robots and rviz can display both the robots.

To resolve the sensor data of the robots you have to provide a namespace for each robot. In the below shown case the scan topic become /robot1/scan and /robot1/camera/image_raw etc and the rviz is able to display the scan data of both the robots.

I use the following launch file:

```
   <launch>
  <!-- start gazebo with an empty plane -->
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

      

  <node launch-prefix="optirun" name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find angen_gazebo)/worlds/angen_empty.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" />

<param name="robot_description"
    command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro" />


  <group ns="robot1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1" />
    <include file="$(find angen_turtlebot)/launch/fuerte_final_r1.launch" >
      <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 9 -y 5 -z 0.05" />
      <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot1" />
</include>
  </group>

  <group ns="robot2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2" />
    <include file="$(find angen_turtlebot)/launch/fuerte_final_r1.launch" >
      <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 9 -y 4 -z 0.05" />
      <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot2" />
</include>
  </group>

</launch>
```

fuerte_final_r1.launch:

```
<launch>

    <arg name="init_pose"/>
    <arg name="robot_name"/>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro'" />

  <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="$(arg init_pose) -unpause -urdf -param /robot_description -model $(arg robot_name) -robotNamespace $(arg robot_name)" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

  <node pkg="diagnostic_aggregator" type="aggregator_node" name="diagnostic_aggregator" >
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/config/diagnostics.yaml" />
  </node>
  
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />
  </node>


  <!-- The odometry estimator -->

  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <!--<param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>-->
  </node>


  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="max_rate" value="20.0"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Fake Laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
    <!-- heights are in the (optical?) frame of the kinect -->
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.15"/>
    <param name="max_height" value="0.15"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Fake Laser (narrow one, for localization -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser_narrow" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
    <!-- heights are in the (optical?) frame of the kinect -->
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.025"/>
    <param name="max_height" value="0.025"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="/narrow_scan"/>
  </node>


</launch>
```

**Regarding the gazebo problem**, many who use robots in gazebo have that problem. I usually do not care about that as long as the robot obeys my navigation commands. But to solve that you can do the following: comment the line in launch file that launches gui, so now you will be launching gazebo without the gui. After launchimg that you can run `rosrun gazebo gui` and both the robots will be visible right from the start.

Read in detail [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/).

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajhamlet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4140/ajhamlet/) on 2013-05-22**:
Thank you for your response. I think I have already mostly figured out the namespace/tf_prefix issue (actually, using an answer to a question you previously asked). Please see the update to my question for more info on the issue I am having.